# Android studio error :Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: android, adb, android-studio-2.1

I am getting this error while I am trying to run my simple program on android studio. Is this happening because of I have already installed some software? this is the list:

1. Eclipse
2. netbeans
3. xampp
4. mysql

I tried all the solution provided in this website, so I didn't catch solution from here:

1. I tried to kill adb and start adb.
2. enable adb integration.
3. and check from android monitor.

please help me, any help will be appreciated and

Answer (score 0):

just delete the other software related to `mysql` like **oracle** database or anything else . After this may be it will work